# Vue.js test:unit with test-utils and Jest : Nested component -Is it possible to mock the $emit(function) from child component?

Tags: unit-testing, vue.js, jestjs, vue-test-utils

Given nested components

the Heading.vue component
         
            {{ $t("lang.views.home.heading.btn__listen") }}
              play_arrow

The nested child component AuioPlayer.vue

```
     <template>
       <div style="display: inline-block;">
         <v-btn id="playPauseBtn">
           ...
         </v-btn>
         <v-btn id="stopBtn" outline icon class="inline teal--text" @click.native="stop()">
           <v-icon>stop</v-icon>
         </v-btn>
         <v-btn id="muteBtn">
           ...
         </v-btn>>
       </div>
     </template>

 <script>
    ...
     methods: {
            stop() {
                this.$data._howl.stop();
                this.$emit("playerStop");
            },
     ...
 </script>
```

Is it possible to test the parent Heading.vue , using shallowMount() mocking the $emit("playerStop") event ... ?

```
     it("should display LISTEN button on child component audioplayer event stop()", () => {
       // given
       wrapper = shallowMount(Heading, { router, i18n });
       wrapper.vm.listening = true;
       // when
       // audioplayer child component should be stubbed
       const audioplayer = wrapper.find('#audioplayer');
       console.log(audioplayer.html());
       // mock the $emit(playerStop) from the child audioplayer stub
       expect(wrapper.vm.listening).toBe(false);
     });
```

UPDATE

I trued 2 solutions without any success

1 / using a spy function

```
it("should display LISTEN button on child component audioplayer event stop()", () => {
  // given
  wrapper = shallowMount(Heading, { router, i18n });
  const spy = jest.fn();
  // wrapper.vm.$on('stopPlayer', spy);  // focus on the call of listener
  wrapper.setData({ listening: true });
  const audioplayer = wrapper.find('audioplayer-stub');
  // when
  audioplayer.trigger('stopPlayer');
  // then
  expect(spy).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
  expect(wrapper.vm.listening).toBe(false);
});
```

2 / Using an async $emit()

```
it("should display LISTEN button on child component audioplayer event stop()", async () => {
  // given
  wrapper = shallowMount(Heading, { router, i18n });
  wrapper.setData({ listening: true });
  const audioplayer = wrapper.find('audioplayer-stub');
  // when
  audioplayer.vm.$emit('stopPlayer');
  await wrapper.vm.$nextTick();
  // then
  expect(wrapper.vm.listening).toBe(false);
});
```

In both cases it seems that if I trigger or emit from the sub-component nothing happen...
As a matter of fact, the emit() should be done from a stop button in the sub-component which is not stubbed at this level ..
Is there anyway to stub it ? 
I want to avoid a mount ... using shallowMount should be sufficient at this level of tets ...

thanks for feedback

Answer (score 2):

SOLVED ... this is one of the traps to avoid while unit testing vue.js :   What should I test ?, not testing the wrong thing....

using test-utils w shallowMount, I should not test for the emi() event from a stubbed component ( this should be tested later within this component)  I should only test the method which will be called ...
In tis case

methods: {
    playerStop() {
      this.listening = false;
    }
  }

tested simply with

```
  it("method playerStop should tpggle listening to false", async () => {
    // given
    wrapper = shallowMount(Heading, { router, i18n });
    wrapper.setData({ listening: true });
    // when
    wrapper.vm.playerStop();
    const playBtn = wrapper.find('#playBtn')
    // then
    expect(wrapper.vm.listening).toBe(false);
  });
```

Comment: That is correct, the test can be better but represents the idea behind of this concept. I recommend read this article https://engineering.doximity.com/articles/five-traps-to-avoid-while-unit-testing-vue-js, is very useful.